# Connect external workers to Cloud Composer airflow

Tags: google-cloud-composer

Is it possible to connect an external worker that is not part of the Cloud Composer Kubernetes cluster? Use case would be connecting a box in a non-cloud data center to a Composer cluster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hybrid clusters are not currently supported in Cloud Composer. If you attempt to roll your own solution on top of Composer, I'd be very interested in hearing what did or didn't work for you.

Comment: That's what I assumed. Thank you!